# Using Proxy with JavaPNS 2.2

Tags: java, proxy, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to use JavaPNS 2.2 to push to apple devices trough a proxy. My java application is running on a jBoss behind a firewall and the only way to communicate with the apple serve is trough that proxy.

```
 public ApplePushNotification(File certificate){

    super();
    ProxyManager.setProxy("myproxy", "myport");
    this.certificate = certificate;

}
```

I am getting this Exception.

```
javapns.communication.exceptions.CommunicationException: Communication exception: java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )"
```

So I read the ProxyManager.java file to find a way for the authorization. I found this:

```
        /**
         * Configure the authorization for the proxy configured through the setProxy method.
         * 
         * @param username the user name to use
         * @param password the password to use
         */
        public static void setProxyBasicAuthorization(String username, String password) {
                setProxyAuthorization(encodeProxyAuthorization(username, password));
        }
```

I tried to use that static method like `ProxyManager.setProxy("myproxy", "myport");` but i am not able to use it.
I would really appreciate for some help. Thanks

Additional links:

http://code.google.com/p/javapns/source/browse/trunk/src/javapns/communication/ProxyManager.java

http://code.google.com/p/javapns/

Comment: I found out that setProxyBasicAuthorization(String username, String password) is a static method included in javapns 2.3_Beta. I will try the Beta.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I make it work with JavaPNS 2.3 Beta.

```
ProxyManager.setProxy("myProxy", "myPort");
ProxyManager.setProxyBasicAuthorization("username", "password");
```

If you want to make it run with JavaPNS 2.2 you need to implement it by yourself. But using 2.3 is a much easier way. Just include javaPNS_2.3_Beta_2.jar to your project as library.

https://github.com/azinman/javapns/blob/master/JavaPNS_2.3_Beta_2.jar?raw=true